# ASP.NET MVC 3: Extension method on UrlHelper/HtmlHelper encodes to HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have written some extension methods for UrlHelper in order to more easily load a ,  or  tag. However, it seems that it renders to literal text in the browser. Here is what I have:

```
public static string Script(this UrlHelper helper, string scriptPath)
        {
            return string.Format(@"<script src=""{0}"" type=""text/javascript""></script>", helper.Content(scriptPath));
        }
```

Here is my .cshtml code:

```
@section HeadContent
{
    @Url.Style("MyStyleName")
    @Url.Script("MyScriptName")
    @Url.MetaKeywords("My Keywords")
    @Url.MetaDescription("Some Description")
}
```

and it comes out in the browser with `&lt;script [etc, etc]&gt;`

If I don't use the extension methods, it will as expected, work correctly... how can I make it work with my extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static string Script(this UrlHelper helper, string scriptPath)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format(@"<script src=""{0}"" type=""text/javascript""></script>", helper.Content(scriptPath)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, friend! That is just what I needed. Only thing is the return type must also be MvcHtmlString. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome mate! Please consider the answer as accepted for other people to know the right answer.

Comment: Indeed. I am waiting until I am able to accept the answer...it says I cannot do that for another 3 minutes! Crazy stuff...

Answer (score 2):

All HTML helpers need to return MvcHtmlString. If you just return a string, it will be treated as an untrusted value and will be HTML-encoded.